# what options of data structure could be used in finding connected components in large datasets?

Tags: data-structures

let's say we have a HashMap with for a graph with node and adjacency list

```
HashMap[node:Long,compId:Long, neighbours:Set[Long])]
```

what is the best way to update all the nodes with the minimum compId(connected component id) and what is the best data structure that can be used when the size of the data is large?

Comment: For anything graphs, I've always resorted to adjacency lists. Easier to manage. But what do you mean by "what is the best way to update all the nodes with the minimum compId"?

Comment: @Zeokav I mean what is the most efficient algorithm or data structure I can use, especially if the data is large, thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use disjoint set data struture, in general case, the amortized complexity would be O(1), very fast!!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is it more efficient than algorithms such as DFS?

Comment: The complexity of DFS is O(V+E), and the disjoint data set is amortized O(1), so the total would be O(1*V)=O(V), so the disjoint set is faster